# Rails - Manipulate params before sending them into address bar on form sumit with GET method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

Is there a way to change params after submitting form, but before sending back answer with rails? I mean without js.
For example I sort something, then submit the search form, and on the server side I want to add sort params, that stored in a variable. I cant use hidden inputs because search form and sort form are two different ones and amount of sorting params is not defined.

Thanks in advance!

I sort files like this `http://example.com/catalog/category?foo=bar&faa=baz`
After submission adress looks like this `http://example.com/catalog/category?search=smthing`
But I want to preserve previous params and to make adress look like this `http://example.com/catalog/category?foo=bar&faa=baz&search=smthing`.

Comment: Not clear about the question

Comment: I send form, form is being processed by server(adding new params), rendering page. I'm asking Is there a way to do it without js, by pure RoR?

Comment: In your form just add :remote => true it does the same ajax file submit but make sure you are not sending unserialized data like file.

Comment: If it's not working without ajax it won't work with it properly. And yes, I tried it alredy - sorting clears after after submitting search form.

Comment: You could put the extra params in the form_tag url.

Comment: You mean something like `form_tag request.url`?